# Как написать SELECT для JSON?

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет! Я имею таблицу `table`в mysql и в ней столбцы `customer_id` = 31, `custom_field`, который хранит значение JSON `{"3":"Ivanovich","2":"nick_Ivan"}`.

Мне нужно выбрать ник `nick_Ivan`.

Как можно написать такой запрос?

```
SELECT `custom_field` FROM `table` WHERE `customer_id` = 31;
```

Отдает: `{"3":"Ivanovich","2":"nick_Ivan"}`

Необходимо получить `nick_Ivan`

Comment: Это не делается средствами SQL. Если уж положили в БД json (чего делать не следовало при работе с БД, которая с json работать не умеет) - то получаете его целиком из БД как сейчас и разбираете уже на том языке из которого вы обращаетесь к БД ...

Comment: @Mike Пишу на PHP, в mysql положила коробка OpenCart, на PHP я знаю как выбрать, просто думал может это возможно сделать по средствам запроса SQL....

Comment: Судя по докам SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(custom_field, '$.2')... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php):

```
select replace(replace(substring_index(custom_field, ':', -1), '"', ''), '}', '')
from test
```

`substring_index(custom_field, ':', -1)` вернет `"nick_Ivan"}`, из которого остаётся убрать лишние символы с помощью `replace`.

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ee7a/3/0).

---

<sub>Можно немного короче, тут как вам удобней:</sub>

```
select replace(substring_index(custom_field, ':"', -1), '"}', '')
from test
```

Comment: второй вариант вообще огонь! Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Второй вариант - огонь до тех пор, пока структура JSON неизменна. Но стоит добавить туда ещё одно поле или сменить порядок...

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> set @x='{"3":"Ivanovich","2":"nick_Ivan"}';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@x,'"2":"',-1),'"',1);
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@x,'"2":"',-1),'"',1) |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| nick_Ivan                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```